# FFmpeg: Generating .ts files and adding Metadata to them

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, metadata, http-live-streaming

Before I was following the steps:

1. Create some metadata:

   ```
   id3taggenerator -o 1.id3 -artist "Emma Stone"
   id3taggenerator -o 2.id3 -artist "Patricia Clarkson"
   ```
2. Create a file saying where to place the metadata in the file:

   ```
   68 id3 /path/to/file/1.id3
   78 id3 /path/to/file/2.id3
   ```
3. Segment the files and include the metadata

   ```
   mediafilesegmenter -f video -M meta.txt video.mp4
   ```

More detail:

http://jmacmullin.wordpress.com/2010/11/03/adding-meta-data-to-video-in-ios/

I want to do something similar to this, but with FFmpeg.

I am also wondering if I could first segment the file into .ts files and add metadata directly to those?

I am having trouble finding the solution on the website. Any help or resources would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use
[`-metadata`](http://github.com/svnpenn/a/blob/7e703d9/scripts/ff-metadata.sh)
flag

```sh
ffmpeg -i maida.mp2 \
  -metadata TITLE='Obelisk' \
  -metadata ALBUM='2003-09-03: Maida Vale, London, UK' \
  -metadata ARTIST='The Mars Volta' \
  -metadata LABEL='' \
  -metadata DATE='2003' \
  maida.flac
```